# Are there obvious reasons to choose between methods and functions in R?

Tags: r, oop, methods

I've written a function to return a class I built that contains some calculations for the data passed to the function.

Once the new object is returned, I intend to print out some of the data in a little "report" and then map the lines contained in the sf slot colored by an attribute the original function calculated.

```
carbon_class <- setClass("carbon_class", slots = c(total_carbon = "numeric", carbon_by_type = "data.frame", trips = "sf"), contains = c("data.frame", "sf"))
```

I was going to define two methods for the class to create the report and map, mainly to practice object oriented programming in R, but as I'm reading about it, I'm having a hard time coming up with a reason to use a method instead of just another function.

Are there obvious use cases for each? I'm reading through Hadley's Advanced R and it talks about *how* to use the S3 and S4 classes/methods, but not *why*.

Thanks

edit: is it for using side effects because technically functions should only return a value without any side effects while its more acceptable for methods to do other things in addition to what they return?

Comment: Maybe this will be interesting to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93N0HdoZW9g

Comment: I think the most obvious case when a method is clearly preferable is to make life easier and more intuitive to end users with generics like `plot` and `print`.  people are used to being able to type an object's name at the console and have some interesting and useful info reported back about the object at the console.  Similarly, people are used to being able to obtain a useful graphical interpretation of an object by using `plot`.  Providing users with these functionalities seems good practice.  If appropriate, providing versions of other generics like `[` and `[<-` may also be good practice

Comment: haven't had a chance to watch that video but looks interesting so thank you. The generic function example makes a lot of sense. Hadn't given any thought to how plot() could handle nearly anything that was passed to it.